# Setting word document created in C# web Response to open in Print Layout

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I am dynamically generating a word document with html in a web application. This works fine however my document opens in Web Layout. I am sure I read somewhere a way to make the generated document open in Print Layout, but I can't find it anywhere now.

```
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=ContentDocument.doc");

    StringBuilder htmlCode = new StringBuilder();
    htmlCode.Append("<html>");
    htmlCode.Append("<head><style type=\"text/css\">body {font-family:arial;font-size:14.5;}</style></head>");
    htmlCode.Append("<body>");

    ... populate htmlCode ...

    htmlCode.Append("</body></html>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(htmlCode.ToString());
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
```

I think it may be a case of adding something specific to the header. Does anyone know how to get the generated document to open in Print Layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open doc in print layout by following code

```
        string strBody = string.Empty;
        strBody = @"<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' " +
        "xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word'" +
        "xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>";

        strBody = strBody + "<!--[if gte mso 9]>" +
        "<xml>" +
        "<w:WordDocument>" +
        "<w:View>Print</w:View>" +
        "<w:Zoom>100</w:Zoom>" +
        "</w:WordDocument>" +
        "</xml>" +
        "<![endif]-->";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",    "inline;filename=ContentDocument.doc");

    StringBuilder htmlCode = new StringBuilder();
    htmlCode.Append("<html>");
    htmlCode.Append("<head>"+strBody+" <style type=\"text/css\">body {font-family:arial;font-size:14.5;}</style></head>");
    htmlCode.Append("<body>");

     ... populate htmlCode ...

    htmlCode.Append("</body></html>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(htmlCode.ToString());
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
```

Comment: I'm putting this directly into the html and it's not working :(